# Passing JS to PHP on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created simple code, that should pass `JS` variable to `PHP` on the same page. This is code that i have written so far:

```
<body>
    <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>
            <p><a onclick="" href="xyz.pdf" download id="xyz" value="x">test pdf</a></p>
            <p><?php print_r($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?></p>
            <p><?php
                if(isset($_POST['city']))
                    {
                        $uid = $_POST['city'];
                        print_r("elo");
                    }
            ?></p>
</body>
<script>
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            if(response.city == 'Białystok') {             
                $("a").click(function() {
                        var city = response.city;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'index.php',
                            data: { city : city },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert(city);
                            }
                        });
                });
            }
    }, "jsonp");
</script>
```

So as u can see, im trying to pass `city` of the user, who downloaded specific file. When i test it locally, after clicking on `download link`
i get `alert` from `success`, so i guess I'm doing it correctly. But my `PHP` above doesn't print anything. There is no `$_POST['city']` on the website.

Do you have any advice what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try doing a die($_POST['city']) instead of print_r, because if you dont end the script, it will continue until the full page is rendered, so it would send back your HTML code as well. Also put your PHP code at the very top of your file (if not in a seperate file, that would be better IMO)

Comment: No, because that bit of PHP already executed before you ran your ajax code. That code ran and created your page, including that HTML and also the ajax code. This was sent to the browser and displayed. _Then_ after that, you run the ajax code, send data to the same page as your current page (this is also a design flaw, btw) and got a response...but you ignore that response and don't do anything with it. You just alert the same "city" variable you sent to the server in the first place, which achieves nothing.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, becouse like i said `isset($_POST['city']` is `false`.

Comment: Your logic is screwy - if you just want to get the result from the ipinfo page and display it on the screen, then `$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            $("body").append("<h3>City is " + response.city + "</h3>");` . Posting back to your original page in this scenario makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm trying to test it. My goal is to send email, after the file is downloaded.

Comment: Well for that you can certainly send an ajax request to the server, but it needs to go to another URL which will just send an email (and return true/false, maybe), not back to your index.php. And what happens if the user clicks on the file to download it _before_ your request to ipinfo has completed? They may only have tiny amount of time to do it, but it's theoretically possible. My advice for that is don't display the download link until you have got the city name. And you still don't need to post back the city name just in order to display it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to print city name after clicking on the link then you don't need php for it.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>
    <p><a onclick="" href="xyz.pdf" download id="xyz" value="x">test pdf</a></p>
    <p><?php print_r($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?></p>
    <p id="result">
        <!-- Result will be printed here -->
    </p>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $("a").click(function() {
            var city = response.city;
            $('p#result').html("City Name: "+city);
        });
    }, "jsonp");
</script>
</html>
```

## If you want something from php side then...

Write this condition in the starting of the file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
        die("...Return something to the call from jquery");
    }
?>
```

and this code should be followed by your remaining code.

Note: If you are expecting JSON data from php then use correct headers and output the json string from php. using die() won't solve the issue.